# Storing Authorization Tokens in React Web App

Tags: reactjs, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I have a react/Gatsby web app, that is using Aws Cognito authentication. The app calls several rest apis hosted at aws api-gateway which again uses Cognito Authorizer.
I need to pass the authentication jwt-token issued by cognito when the user first logs in in the authorization header of each request sent to the api-gateway.
Where should I safely store that token?

Thanks,

Comment: on your server! -- more seriously, what's your question? Do you mean in the database vs. in a file? encrypted vs. not?

Comment: one idea is that you can store the token in localstorage.

Comment: @ChristianFritz it is a ReactJs website and runs completely on db access through apis. I am asking where I should store the session authorization Jwt for the authenticated user to be able to access apis. Where can be anything you propse Localstorage, session cookie etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your first preference is always `httponly` cookies and if it not possible then you can go for local storage.

here are the best answers you can get.

[Local Storage vs Cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220660/local-storage-vs-cookies)